# Python manager.dict() is very slow compared to regular dict

Tags: python, python-2.7, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, multiprocessing-manager

I have a dict to store objects:

```
jobs = {}
job = Job()
jobs[job.name] = job
```

now I want to convert it to use manager dict because I want to use multiprocessing and need to share this dict amonst processes

```
mgr = multiprocessing.Manager()
jobs = mgr.dict()
job = Job()
jobs[job.name] = job
```

just by converting to use manager.dict() things got extremely slow.

For example, if using native dict, it only took .65 seconds to create 625 objects and store it into the dict.

The very same task now takes 126 seconds!

Any optimization i can do to keep manager.dict() on par with python {}?

Comment: was it 0.65 seconds or 65 seconds?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem is that each insert is quite slow for some reason (117x slower on my machine), but if you update your `manager.dict()` with a normal dict, it will be a single and fast operation.

```
jobs = {}
job = Job()
jobs[job.name] = job
# insert other jobs in the normal dictionary

mgr = multiprocessing.Manager()
mgr_jobs = mgr.dict()
mgr_jobs.update(jobs)
```

Then use the `mgr_jobs` variable.

Another option is to use the widely adopted `multiprocessing.Queue` class.

Comment: this would solve the delay in the initial creation of jobs. but what if i need to insert/delete many times?  any idea how lookup performs for manager.dict() compared to regular dict?

Comment: it looks like insertion is terrible for manager.Queue() as well. any idea how lookup and deletion perform for manager.dict() compared to regular dict?

Comment: multiprocessing.Queue is much faster! it is still sharable between the processes right? Any idea why would someone use manager.Queue() over multiprocessing.Queue() ?

Comment: i wish they have multiprocessing.dict() because i do need to use dict hmmm

Comment: I tried Queue too. Still ridiculously slow. Makes me want to go back to C.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using `mgr.dict()` inside a loop in your pool. You can use a local normal dict to store results temporarily and then update your `mgr.dict()` outside the loop like `your_mgr_dict.update(local_dict)`